# How to start my td's as revealed and unreveal them on click

Tags: javascript

[Example of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IM3A.png) So basically im making a minesweeper game with PHP/Javascript. The thing is that I would like my td's to be revealed at first, and when you click on a td it unreveals itself including the content. Since im very new to programming I need all the help I can get. And if possible, explain what does what with comments or so. posted below is my javascript that im using. If you need the PHP code as well, let me know :)
BUG = mine

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td").click(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == '') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'DarkGray');
            console.log("Je hebt op een leeg vakje geklikt");
        }

        if ($(this).text() == 'BUG') {
            $("td:contains('BUG')").css('background-color', 'Gray');
            $("td:not(:contains('BUG'))").css('background-color', 'DarkGray');
            console.log("Je hebt op een bug geklikt");
        }

        $("#renew").click(function () {
            location.reload();
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code that you are using? It seems good enough for me..

Comment: Hello! What are you having problem with? Can you describe the issue? The provided code will highlight all BUG td's with a background color once the mine is clicked, so I'm assuming that is not what is intended? Or do you want to know how you can hide and later reveal the text? (which cannot be done with background color, so that could be the other issue).

Comment: Yeah basically I want my TD's to be white at the start and when I click on one it either contains a BUG or a empty TD. So it would basically unreveal the content of the TD on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to hide / reveal specific table cell texts based on user clicks.

You cannot do that with background-color, since that will not override the text (the text will still be written above the background color).

Trying not to diverge from your current implementation, you could make all your td cells have font-size: 0px, and then when the user clicks, change the font size to be mlarger than 0 so the text shows (along with changing backgrounds and whatever else you want).

**CSS**

```
td{
font-size: 0px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("td").click(function () {

    $(this).css('font-size', '18px');

    if ($(this).text() == '') {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'DarkGray');
        console.log("Je hebt op een leeg vakje geklikt");
    }

    if ($(this).text() == 'BUG') {
        $("td:contains('BUG')").css('background-color', 'Gray');
        $("td:not(:contains('BUG'))").css('background-color', 'DarkGray');
        console.log("Je hebt op een bug geklikt");
    }

    $("#renew").click(function () {
        location.reload();
    });
})
```

});

**Edit:**
This is a clunky way of implementing the desired functionality. A better way would be to, instead of adding BUG text directly into your td, write your td to hold information about whether or not it contains a BUG.

For example:

```
<td data-type="BUG"></td>
<td data-type="NOT"></td>
<td data-type="BUG"></td>
```

Then, when the user clicks on a td, you check if data-type is BUG, and if it is, add 'BUG' into the clicked td, and in that way you 'reveal' what the td was.

For example with before mentioned html:

```
$("td").click(function(){
   if($(this).attr("data-type") === "BUG"){
       //user clicked on a td with a BUG
       $(this).text('BUG');
   }
});
```

Comment: Even though this helped me so much into creating what I want, I must admit that I took a bit of a different approach. Instead of making the font size 0px and revealing them as 17px on click I made the color of 'BUG' white. By doing so I also created an else statement that echo'd a div with a class. Then I gave that class some css changes and now it works as it should. I also added some user-select options so they wont be able to drag their mouse over the grid and see where the bugs are. But since your answer was extremely usefull for me I accepted it as an answer ;)